# How to hide the keyboard after moving another tab using the method in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, tabs

How to hide the keyboard after moving another tab using the method in android ?
My Code switch in tabs - how methond hide keybord

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Tab2Fragment();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = null;
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried closing the keyboard programmatically on click on another fragment ?
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your onCreate() in Fragments.

```
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);// for hide keypad
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using following method:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(View viewFocus) {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        if (viewFocus != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) viewFocus.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(viewFocus.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

In Activity/Fragment call this method like:

```
hideSoftKeyboard(getCurrentFocus())
```

Hope it help you !

Comment: on MainActivity ?

Comment: @AlhamsyaBintangDyasta inside onCreateView of eachFragment

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to hide the keyboard:

```
    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity act){
        View view = act.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)act.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

and call it where ever you initiate you TabLayout, like:

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
           hideKeyboard(myActivity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```